# FileStream.Position returns a negative value

Tags: c#, filestream

I am writing to a file stream and when i want to close a file I update some location values of the file, for that I read out `FileStream.Position` and this value is negative when file size is 2 GB, how is it possible to have negative value for position ?

Folling is the code I am using.

```
int SomePosition = 78;
long lastPos = _fileStream.Position;
_fileStream.Position = SomePosition;
byte[] bArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(someValue);
_fileStream.Write(bArray, 0, bArray.Length);
_fileStream.Position = lastPos;
```

In the above code `long lastPos = _fileStream.Position;` `lastPos` becomes negative.

Comment: Can you show some code? Seems odd as `FileStream.Position` is a `long`.

Comment: @Lloyd maybe that's the problem: the `long` is being cast into and `int`

Comment: @Rik We don't know that until he shows some code. However seems logical with arithmetic overflow, that's what usually happens.

Comment: Is the value you get `-2147483571`, by any chance?

Comment: What happens if you do `_fileStream.Position = (long)SomePosition;`?

Comment: @Rik No it's -2147483648

Comment: @Bovi that is Int32.MinValue, the lowest value that can be represented by an `int`. So it would be very conincidental if it's not some overflow issue.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to store the value in an `int` variable?

`FileStream.Position` is a `long`, and casting a value higher than `int.Maxvalue` to an `int` could result in a negative value.

Comment: I am using a long variable to store the value , you can see that in the code snippet. long lastPos = _fileStream.Position;